# PriorityQueue ordering issue

Tags: java

I have a PriorityQueue of Vehicles that has one item that is not ordering correctly.  I assume there is something in my compareTo that is wonky, but I haven't been able to find it.

```
public class Vehicle implements Comparable<Vehicle> {

private int id;
private Calendar queueTime;
private int type;
private int size;
 }

@Override
public int compareTo(Vehicle vehicle) {
    if (this.getType() == vehicle.getType()) {
        if (this.getSize() == vehice.getSize()) {
            return (this.queueTime.compareTo(vehicle.queueTime));
        } else if (this.getSize().compareTo(vehicle.getSize()) > 0) {
            return -1;
        } else {
            return 1;
        }
    } else if (this.getType().compareTo(vehicle.getType()) > 0) {
        return -1;
    } else {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

I have a main class which creates the PriorityQueue, creates a bunch of Vehicle objects and then adds them to the queue.

```
Queue<Vehicle> currentQueue = new PriorityQueue<Vehicle>();
Vehicle smallPass1 = new Vehicle(1, Calendar.getInstance(), 1, 0);
Vehicle smallCargo1 = new Vehicle(2, Calendar.getInstance(), 0, 0);
Vehicle largePass1 = new Vehicle(3, Calendar.getInstance(), 1, 1);
Vehicle largeCargo1 = new Vehicle(4, Calendar.getInstance(), 0, 1);
Vehicle smallPass2 = new Vehicle(5, Calendar.getInstance(), 1, 0);
Vehicle smallCargo2 = new Vehicle(6, Calendar.getInstance(), 0, 0);
Vehicle largePass2 = new Vehicle(7, Calendar.getInstance(), 1, 1);
Vehicle largeCargo2 = new Vehicle(8, Calendar.getInstance(), 0, 1);
```

I am expecting this output:

```
Queue is: [
Vehicle [id=3, queueTime=1396824774459], 
Vehicle [id=7, queueTime=1396824774459],  
Vehicle [id=5, queueTime=1396824774459], 
Vehicle [id=1, queueTime=1396824774458], 
Vehicle [id=8, queueTime=1396824774459], 
Vehicle [id=4, queueTime=1396824774459], 
Vehicle [id=2, queueTime=1396824774459], 
Vehicle [id=6, queueTime=1396824774459]]
```

But I get this instead:

```
Queue is: [
Vehicle [id=3, queueTime=1396824774459], 
Vehicle [id=7, queueTime=1396824774459], 
Vehicle [id=8, queueTime=1396824774459], 
Vehicle [id=5, queueTime=1396824774459], 
Vehicle [id=1, queueTime=1396824774458], 
Vehicle [id=2, queueTime=1396824774459], 
Vehicle [id=4, queueTime=1396824774459], 
Vehicle [id=6, queueTime=1396824774459]]
```

Comment: How are the priorities being set?  The queue has its own priorities, separate from what the `compareTo` induces.

Comment: @DavidWallace: I disagree. If no Comparator is used, then the natural ordering ***is*** in fact used to determine priorities or order.

Comment: You get this output how? If you're not removing items from the PQ you won't get its order. See the Javadoc.

Comment: @DavidWallace No it doesn't. PriorityQueue doesn't 'have its own priorities'. It has what the Comparator or Comparable delivers, period.

Comment: True, but OP hasn't shown us how the queue is being created.  Presumably though, they are not providing a `Comparator` - otherwise they would have shown it here.  So I take back my remarks.  This `compareTo` is what matters.

Comment: I presume the third constructor argument is the type and the fourth is the size?

Comment: The variable `aircraft` in the first `else-if` clause should definitely be `vehicle` - is this just a copy/paste error?  Because it could actually cause the problem that you're seeing.

Comment: Yes, that is just a copy/paste error.  I am not using an iterator to get the results...I realize iterator does not produce sorted results.  I am simply printing the entire queue contents.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your queue and the `compareTo` method are likely working correctly. Note what the API says about it:

> This class and its iterator implement all of the optional methods of the Collection and Iterator interfaces. The Iterator provided in method iterator() is **not guaranteed to traverse the elements of the priority queue in any particular order**. If you need ordered traversal, consider using Arrays.sort(pq.toArray()).

The order is apparent when you retrieve items from the queue via the operations poll, remove, peek, and element.

Comment: That's a good point.  If this thing is implemented as a heap, for example, under the hood, then yeah you're likely to see some really funny things when you serialize it.  (in fact maintaining a full sort on the priority queue is often very inefficient for the task)

Comment: @DrLivingston It is implemented as a heap: see the Javadoc.

Comment: I am not using an iterator to get the results...I realize iterator does not produce sorted results. I am simply printing the entire queue contents....System.out.println(currentQueue).

Comment: @Ci-CiMillsThomson: yes of course you are using an iterator. The `toString()` method used by your collection to print out its results uses an iterator behind the scenes. One more reason you should never rely on the results of `toString()` for production code.